# No puedo exportar factura al archivo txt

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, javafx, java-8

Estimados Amigos:
Estoy tratando de exportar mi factura al archivo txt para ser impreso en la impresora matricial desde javaweb JSF(JavaFaces) y me sale un error de mensaje: 
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Character width in pixels or page width in characters must be specified and must be greater than zero.
Por favor necesito que me oriente, en que he fallado.

Aqui le demuestro mi código:
ReporteFactura.java

```
   public void exportarFacturaText(String ruta, String archivo, Integer codF, BigDecimal toTales, String simMone) throws ClassNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException, IOException, Exception {
    Connection conexion;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/erpcarbonstar?useSSL=false", "root", "10260429");
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + archivo);
    ServletOutputStream outstream = response.getOutputStream();

    Locale milocal = new Locale("en", "PE");
    this.totaligv = new BigDecimal("0");
    this.totales = new BigDecimal("0");
    int x = 1;

    this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    parametroDao parDao = new parametroDaoImp();
    this.transaction = this.session.beginTransaction();

    this.parametro = parDao.obtenerDatosParametro(this.session, x);
    if (this.parametro.getIdParametro().equals(x) && this.parametro.getMonedaParametro1().equals(simMone)) {
        BigDecimal dividoigv = this.parametro.getImpuestoParametroDec().divide(new BigDecimal(100.0));
        BigDecimal igv = toTales.multiply(dividoigv);
        this.totaligv = igv;
        this.txtmonedas = this.parametro.getDesignacionParametro1();
    } else if (this.parametro.getIdParametro().equals(x) && this.parametro.getMonedaParametro2().equals(simMone)) {
        BigDecimal dividoigv = this.parametro.getImpuestoParametroDec().divide(new BigDecimal(100.0));
        BigDecimal igv = toTales.multiply(dividoigv);
        this.totaligv = igv;
        this.txtmonedas = this.parametro.getDesignacionParametro2();
    }
    this.totales = toTales.add(this.totaligv);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("######0.00");
    conversionMontoLetra numletra = new conversionMontoLetra();
    String montosletras = numletra.Convertir(df.format(this.totales), true);
    String txtmontosletras = "SON : " + montosletras + this.txtmonedas;

    //Se definen los parametros que el reporte necesita
    Map parameter = new HashMap();
    parameter.put("numerosfacturas", codF);
    parameter.put("igv", this.totaligv);
    parameter.put("totales", this.totales);
    parameter.put("montoletra", txtmontosletras);
    parameter.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, milocal);
    parameter.put(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_WIDTH, 800);
    parameter.put(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_HEIGHT, 400);

    try {
        File file = new File(ruta);

        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(file.getPath());
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameter, conexion);
        JRTextExporter exporter = new JRTextExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(outstream));
        exporter.exportReport();

        outstream.flush();
        outstream.close();

    } catch (JRException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    } finally {
        if (conexion != null) {
            try {
                conexion.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FacturaBean.java es una parte del código:

```
    public void verFacturaMatrixNavegadorPDF() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, Exception {

    int cf = this.numerofact;
    BigDecimal tt = this.toTaless;
    String mm = this.simmon;
    DecimalFormat serie = new DecimalFormat("000000");

    reporteFactura rFactura = new reporteFactura();

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) facesContext.getExternalContext().getContext();
    String ruta = servletContext.getRealPath("/Reportes/facturamatrixReport.jasper");
    String archivo = "FacturaNro" + serie.format(cf) + ".txt";

    //rFactura.verFacturaPDF(ruta, archivo, cf, tt, mm);
    rFactura.exportarFacturaText(ruta, archivo, cf, tt, mm);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

}
```

pequeño código de la parte de la vista:

```
                            <h:outputText value=" "/>
                        <h:commandLink id="reportefactura3" target="_blank" actionListener="#{facturaBean.pedirFactura(ft.numeroFactura, ft.totalVenta, ft.moneda.simboloMoneda)}"                                           
                                       title="Imprimir en la impresora Matricial" action="#{facturaBean.verFacturaMatrixNavegadorPDF()}" >
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/impresoramatricial.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregando 2 propiedades mas:

```
parameter.put(TextReportConfiguration.PROPERTY_CHARACTER_WIDTH, 7.238);
parameter.put(TextReportConfiguration.PROPERTY_CHARACTER_HEIGHT, 13.948);
```

El siguiente link te puede ayudar [TextReportConfiguration](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/text/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

gracias por la información. Ya he intentado poner a lo indicado. al final tuve que adicionar este código en el archivo jrxml de ireport y con eso funciona.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.width" value="7.238"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.height" value="13.948"/>
```